# Getting amplitude from a webkit-speech field

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit, speech-recognition

I'm using a input field with x-webkit-speech for voice input / speech recognition. Is there any way to extract the amplitude of the input. If not, is there some other way I could get the amplitude. I primarily need the amplitude to visualize the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to extract the amplitude of the input.

No

> If not, is there some other way I could get the amplitude.

Use flash

> I primarily need the amplitude to visualize the input.

Not a great idea at this time